# how to give c# Rdlc report, untyped dataset in c# code

Tags: dataset, datasource, rdlc, reporting-services

I have a small windows application with some calculations and have my untyped dataset populated namely "progDS". I have used MS Access Database. If I use typed dataset, the report picks each and every row and displays it on the reportviewer (that is not my requirement). What I had been trying to do is display only three rows that must contain the new calculated fields.

The application is for my department that receives forms of students, specific programs (that dataset 'progDS' contains) are offered. RDLC report, and ReportViewer only takes typed dataset, how to over-ride or change the dataset and give mine i.e. 'progDS'.

I have the ReportViewer on another form, and I am able to get the dataset 'progDS' into that form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace FreshFormReport
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        Form1 ObjFomr1 = new Form1();
        DataSet dsF3 = new DataSet();
        DataSet2 dataSet = new DataSet2();
        DataTable dtF3 = new DataTable();
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();


        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the    'DataSet2.RpTable' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                //    this.RpTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.RpTable);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                //    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rptSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("dsF3", dsF3.Tables["Porgrams"]);
                 reportViewer1.Reset();
                 reportViewer1.ProcessingMode =    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
                Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport localRep = reportViewer1.LocalReport;
                localRep.Refresh();
                localRep.ReportEmbeddedResource = "C:\\Users\\*******  \\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\FreshFormReport\\FreshFormReport\\MyReport.rdlc";

                rptSource.Name = "MyReport";
                //RpTableTableAdapter.Fill(DataSet2.RpTable);
                rptSource.Value = DataSet2.RpTable;
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptSource);
                //string name = localRep.GetDataSourceNames().ToString();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\\Users\\******  \\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\FreshFormReport\\FreshFormReport\\MyReport.rdlc";

                //reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource =  "MyReport.rdlc";
                //reportViewer1.Refresh();
                reportViewer1.Refresh();
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
            }

        }

        public void F3function(DataSet ds, DataTable dt)
        {
            try
            {
                dsF3 = ds;
                dtF3 = dt;
                bs.DataSource = dt;
            }
             catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```